# MariaDB 10.3.14 RANK() OVER function throwing syntax error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have recently upgraded my MariaDB 5.5 to MariaDB 10.3.14 specifically to be able to use the RANK() OVER function that was introduced after 10.2.

After going through the upgrade process, I still get the same syntax error message I was getting on 5.5.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            at line 2
```

I'm trying to understand why after the upgrade I still get the same error.
Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT member_id, total_pts, correct_predictions, correct_goals
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            total_pts DESC,
            correct_predictions DESC,
            correct_goals DESC
        ) rank
FROM quiniela_1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a comma after `SELECT member_id, total_pts, correct_predictions, correct_goals` so that your query reads:

```
SELECT member_id, total_pts, correct_predictions, correct_goals,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            total_pts DESC,
            correct_predictions DESC,
            correct_goals DESC
        ) rank
FROM quiniela_1;
```

Comment: Notice how the error message pointed to exactly where the problem was (at `RANK`, or immediately before it).